# One-level drop-down menu from ul list styled with css possible?

Tags: html, css, menu, html-lists

I have a list of items of which only the first is visible and on list hover shows all items with **side effect of changing the position of surrounding content**. How to evade this unwanted effect?

Here is an example list: 
http://jsfiddle.net/dsbonev/z8Sjy/

All examples that I checked for styling menus have a two-level structure (parent -> children). On parent hover children are shown. But I don't have a parent to hover onto nor I want to promote one of the children as a parent by moving it out of the list and thus breaking the semantic of the markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out! This is what I wanted:

http://jsfiddle.net/z8Sjy/

I accept comments with shortcomings or improvements of this method.

**HTML**

```
<div class="list-wrapper">
    <ul class="items">
        <li>stackoverflow</li>
        <li>superuser</li>
        <li>serverfault</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.list-wrapper, .items {
    display: inline-block;
}

.list-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 1em;
}

.items {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
}

.items > li:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
}

.items:hover > li:not(:first-child) {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: +1 Seems like a reasonable solution and is very similar to @JamesMontagne's answer except maybe slightly more encapsulated. Should work fine as long as there isn't the chance of going onto multiple lines. Also, check out the CSS selectors in my answer if you would like to make your CSS a little more backwards compatable.

Comment: @MyHeadHurts JamesMontagne's solution requires setting a padding of surrounding elements, but this drop-down is reused more than once on a page and the content around it could be anything - from <h1> to <img>. Thanks for the CSS selector hint.

Comment: No problem, glad they helped. In regards to James's answer I was refering more to the `position: absolute` part of your solution. The fact that you have wrapped the menu in an element with relative positioning and a set height is definately a stronger approach and that was what I was referring to when I said it was more encapsulated. It is a good answer, hence the up-vote :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `display: none` & `display: block` use `visibility: hidden` & `visibility: visible`. That way they take up the space in the HTML document, but are not shown:

**Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/z8Sjy/3/**

#### Edit

The following CSS would be more cross-browser compatable for showing / hiding *"not first-child"* elements as the selector `:not` is actually CSS3.

```
.items > li:first-child ~ li {
    display: none;
}

.items:hover > li:first-child ~ li {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: I think you pasted the wrong URL, because that is the same URL posted in the question, unchanged.

Comment: Doh! Thanks for pointing that out - I forgot to click the `update` button. I also think I got the wrong end of the stick for the question after reading your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could position the list absolutely and then add padding to the paragraph to compensate.

http://jsfiddle.net/z8Sjy/2/